# Saving entity using prorotype of objects in properties

Tags: java, jpa, orm, persistence, entities

I'm using JPA and have next entity

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    int id;
    String name;

    @ManyToOne
    Employee manager;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="manager",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    Set<Employee> subordinaries;

 // constructors , getters, setters 
}
```

Can I use prototype of property object for saving? It's works but I'm not shure that it's good practice. This is DAO class:

```
public class CompanyOrm {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="springHibernate")
    EntityManager em;

    ...

    @Transactional
    public void addEmployee(int id, String name, int managerId){

        //Using prototype of object manager - not 
        //object retrived from database with 
        //em.find(Employee.class, managerId)
        //where filled only id

        Employee prototype = new Employee();
        prototype.setId(managerId);
        Employee e = new Employee(id, name, prototype);
        em.persist(e);
    }

   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may work but it's error-prone, since the prototype instance is not managed.

You should use `em.getReference(Employee.class, managerId)` to create the referenced entity. It returns an uninitialized proxy on the entity, without going to the database.